# drools kjar Query does not exist

Tags: java, drools

I have been working on a drools project and we recently started building our spreadsheets into kjars using kie-maven-plugin. Right now, to test the kjar build, I have 1 spreadsheet and 1 query. The issue I am having is the query is not found. I am not sure if the spreadsheet rules are found, but I am getting a session.

Sorry for the long post, but I really need help. Full info below...

My kmodule.xml:

```
<kbase name="com.foo.ratings.decisionTables.flex">
      <ksession name="flex"/>
</kbase>
```

My query:

```
package com.foo.ratings.decisionTables.flex;

import com.foo.ratings.tangerinegin.facts.*;

query "getFlexCode"
    $flexGroupCd: FlexGroupCdFact()
end
```

The error:

```
2017-11-02 11:01:35.727 ERROR 34585 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Query 'getFlexCode' does not exist] with root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Query 'getFlexCode' does not exist
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl$ExecuteQuery.execute(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:907) ~[drools-core-7.1.0.Final.jar!/:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.phreak.SynchronizedPropagationList$1.execute(SynchronizedPropagationList.java:53) ~[drools-core-7.1.0.Final.jar!/:7.1.0.Final]
```

We have looked inside the kjar, and we see the kmodule.xml, as well as the kbase.cache. Here is the expanded jar:

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 localadmin  staff  238 Nov  2 11:17 META-INF
-rw-r--r--  1 localadmin  staff    0 Nov  2 10:54 application.properties
drwxr-xr-x  3 localadmin  staff  102 Nov  2 10:54 com
```

com expands to com/foo/ratings/decisionTables/flex and contains both my spreadsheet and my query drl file.

Here is META-INF expanded:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 localadmin  staff     100 Nov  2 10:56 MANIFEST.MF
drwxr-xr-x  3 localadmin  staff     102 Nov  2 10:56 com
-rw-r--r--  1 localadmin  staff  752813 Nov  2 10:56 kmodule.info
-rw-r--r--  1 localadmin  staff     209 Nov  2 10:54 kmodule.xml
drwxr-xr-x  4 localadmin  staff     136 Nov  2 10:54 maven
```

META-INF/com expands to com/foo/ratings/decisionTables/flex and contains my kbase.cache.

My pom:

```
<groupId>com.foo.ratings.tangerineGin</groupId>
<artifactId>MyFlex</artifactId>
<version>1.0.2</version>

<packaging>kjar</packaging>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
      <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0.Final</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

My kmodule.info:

```
<rulesByPackage>
    <entry>
      <string>com.foo.ratings.decisionTables.flex</string>
      <set>
        <string>getFlexCode</string>
      </set>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <string>com.foo.decisionTable.calculateFlexGroup_CO</string>
      <set>
        <string>calculate_flex_959</string>
```

I am obviously missing something simple, but I am really spinning my wheels at this point. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Edit: kmodule is added

```
Found kmodule: jar:file:/Users/localadmin/workspace/TangerineGin/TangerineGin-server/build/libs/tangerine-gin-server-1.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/TangerineGin-flex-1.0.6.jar!/META-INF/kmodule.xml
Unable to find pom.properties in /Users/localadmin/workspace/TangerineGin/TangerineGin-server/build/libs/tangerine-gin-server-1.0.jar
Unable to load pom.properties from/Users/localadmin/workspace/TangerineGin/TangerineGin-server/build/libs/tangerine-gin-server-1.0.jar
Cannot find maven pom properties for this project. Using the container's default ReleaseId
KieModule was added: ZipKieModule[releaseId=org.default:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT,file=/Users/localadmin/workspace/TangerineGin/TangerineGin-server/build/libs/tangerine-gin-server-1.0.jar]
```

Comment: Add a simple high-salience rule with empty LHS and a println on the RHS and see whether this fires. If not, then the DRL isn't added to the KieBase, for some reason (I'm too ignorant to see). But it should narrow this down.

Comment: Thanks, we have tried that and found that the drl rues are not found, even though the kmodule was found. See edit.

Comment: We figured out what the problem was. The server that contained the kjar was not set up as a maven project. We aded a pom.properties to META-INF/maven.<groupId>.<artifactId> and it works.